# Office365 Windows Application using MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, api, mvvm, office365

I am newly developing office365 desktop application. I got some sample code from [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Win-Snippets). I followed the steps mentioned in `REGISTER YOUR APP`. I am able to get all the details like contact, emails and calendars without a problem.

Questions:

1. By using MVVC platform can i generate a desktop application?
2. How can i connect to the Exchange Server with Oauth token? Any example? Actually i followed the following procedure:

   ```
   AuthenticationContext authenticationContext =

   new AuthenticationContext(“login.windows.net/treyresearch1.onmicrosoft.com”);
   AuthenticationResult result =

   await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(“myappurl”,“2b8606b7-6bad-4e8b-ac3c-1356aca8ab0e”);
   ```

   But getting `AuthenticationContext` does not exist. What is the service that I need to import to run this?
3. How can i add a delegate using Exchange Server?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example on the link below, I also used it as started point for my WPF application. It has a example WPF project:

[Office365Api.Overview example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Office365Api.Overview)

This example also contains some helper classes for Authentication etc.